# Can one use iPhone as an AirPlay target and play audio from Mac?

Tags: macos, iphone, audio, airplay

How can I use my iPhone as a target device for AirPlay, so that I can listen to the audio output from my Mac? It would be nice to be able to not have to re-pair the bluetooth headset and listen to the audio from my computer.

Is it possible? Any app to accomplish this?

Answer (score 1):

You can do this with Rogue Amoeba's [Airfoil](https://www.rogueamoeba.com/airfoil/mac/). Install the Airfoil software on the Mac and the Airfoil Satellite app on the iPhone.

It's commercial software but there is a free trial.

Answer (score 0):

An iPhone cannot be an AirPlay target. The easiest solution is to use Airpods or Beats headphones as they more seamlessly (though not perfectly) move from one device to another.
That said, even if you use non Apple headphones, you shouldn't be needing to re-pair them, did you mean hitting connect in Bluetooth?

Answer (score 0):

Found a solution. I just installed Kodi which runs as a AirPlay reciever, so that I can get the computer audio played on my phone, works flawless.